# Quant Interview Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do you impress the interviewer, when he asks you to compute $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}$?

Comment: To impress you would start by properly defining it as the limit of a recurrence, then show that this recurrence converges (showing that the expression is well-defined) and then in the end you find the limit.

Comment: By saying *the limit is trivially $2$ by the Banach fixed point theorem*.

Answer (score 3):

Just note that
$$x^2-2=x$$
I bet even a quant can solve that. (I'm allowed to make that joke, I'm actually a quant myself.)

Answer (score 0):

If $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\dots}}}$, then $x=\sqrt{2+x}$ so that $x^2-x-2=0$. Thus $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(2)}}{2}=2$.